# How to display image on successful image POST?

Tags: ajax, form-data

I am currently using Ajax to POST formdata (images) to my PHP application, where I then simply save the image.

My form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileUploadForm">
    <label>
      Open file dialog
      <input type="file" style="position: fixed; top: -100em" name="file">
    </label>
</form>
```

My script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#upload-pictures").click(function(){
   var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/index/index.php",
        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
            
            $('body').html('<img src="' + data + '" />'); //doesn't work
        }
    });
  });
});
```

What's the best way for me to display this image (after it has been successfully uploaded) on my webpage? I tried using 
 `$('body').html('<img src="' + data + '" />');`
but it didn't seem to work.

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What’s your PHP script, what does it return? If it’s raw image data, you can use the data: pseudoprotocol, such as '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+window.btoa(data)+'" />'

Comment: I just echo out the contents of `file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);`

Comment: I've tried adding in your img src, but now I'm getting this console error message: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range

Comment: Try printing base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) in php and removing the window.btoa function.

Comment: @RatajS, still not working. I think this 

`$('body').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)))+'');`

is the closest I've got to having it working. The Jpeg image that I upload as a test seems to contain the JFIF, as expected in the console log.

Comment: JFIF ... ���� ... 
is my output

Comment: Ah, I got it working. Looks like you were right before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @RatajS for the help. I finally got it working:

In my PHP:

```
$contents =  base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
```

In my HTML/Javascript:

```
$("<img>").attr({src: "data:image/jpeg;base64," +data}).appendTo("body");
```